# Drools not able to load rules in Spring Boot Project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, drools, business-rules, kie

I am using the Drools 7.5.0-final in the spring Boot project.

I am working on a multi-module Gradle project. 
Rules and kmodule.xml is present in the sub-module project. This module is packaged as a Jar inside a fat spring boot Jar file.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
<!-- <configuration>
  <property key="drools.propertySpecific" value="ALLOWED"/>
</configuration> -->

<kbase name="rules.employee.tax"   packages="uk.gov.hmrc.itmp.service.application.rules.employee.tax" > 
<ksession name="rules.employee.tax.session" type="stateful"  />
<ksession name="rules.employee.tax.statelesssession" type="stateless" />
</kbase>  
</kmodule>
```

I am building the container from the classpath.

```
KieContainer kContainer = kieService.newKieClasspathContainer();
```

on server start-up **(java -jar)** it loads the Kmodule.xml and prints all the kbase and sessionName.

But when I fire rules it returns **`zero rules fired`**.

**It works fine when I run as spring boot app from Eclipse.**
Please help.

Comment: is there anyone else who got the same issue? I have a reproducer if it helps to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was the bug in Drools and has been solved under this JIRA :
https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-2311?_sscc=t

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in the KieServices and the SPring Boot uber jar. There is a work around posted here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-usage/odQjmBess5A

Basically, configure the Spring Boot Maven Plugin to unpack the kie jar(s).

```
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <requiresUnpack>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
                            <artifactId>kproject1</artifactId>
                        </dependency>

                       <dependency>
                           <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
                           <artifactId>kproject2</artifactId>
                       </dependency>
                    </requiresUnpack>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following dependencies

```
implementation group: 'org.kie', name: 'kie-api', version: '7.16.0.Final'
implementation group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-core', version: '7.16.0.Final'
implementation group: 'org.drools', name: 'drools-compiler', version: '7.16.0.Final'
implementation group: 'org.kie', name: 'kie-spring', version: '7.16.0.Final'
```

and remove `spring-boot-devtools` dependency if you have one.

(This worked for me.)

Answer (score 0):

When using spring-boot-devtools, this is because your facts usually gets loaded using "Restart Classloader" and your Drools classes using "Base Classloader". Therefore the fact objects does not match when your rules are executed.

I resolved this problem by using "Restart Classloader" for Drools classes too, by creating a file src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-devtools.properties in my spring-boot-application with following content:

```
restart.include.dools=/(drools|kie)\-.*\.jar
```

[Related spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-customizing-classload)

Comment: I was not using the devtools

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after upgrading to java17 and latest version of drools 8.34.0.Final (from version 7.x). The rules were no longer located from kmodule.xml files. The hint about the root cause of the issue was console log (easy to miss):

```
2023-02-23 15:01:35.467546300 DEBUG 18840   [DEX    ] [main] o.d.c.k.b.i.ClasspathKieProject          :423 : KieModule URL type=file url=/C:/aaa/target/classes
2023-02-23 15:01:35.467546300 ERROR 18840   [DEX    ] [main] o.d.c.k.b.i.ClasspathKieProject          :143 : Unable to build index of kmodule.xml url=file:/C:/aaa/target/classes/META-INF/kmodule.xml
You're trying to perform a xml related operation without the necessary xml support for drools. Please add the module org.drools:drools-xml-support to your classpath.
```

The solution was to add the newly shipped jar with xml support:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-xml-support</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

NOTE: all the plugins and jars required are listed below.
Also I still have this  `<requiresUnpack>` option active, which you can find in another answer

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${drools-version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            
                      <!-- Drools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-bom</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-mvel</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-xml-support</artifactId>
            <version>${drools-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```